# SSRS Parameters for "Receipt Info"

Tags: reporting-services

I have a "receipt Information Report".  For instance

```
ID         Name                Date             Createtor        Payment Date

1          Bob               12.12.2012           bb               01.01.2013

2          Smith             15.01.2010           smt              15.02.2011

3          Peter             21.02.2011           ptr                  null       

4          Sarah             18.06.2012           srh              23.07.2012
```

I want to add a parameter into this report like that;

- List all the receipts(Then it will list the report above)
- List all the receipts which have been created by Sarah
- List all the receipt which have been paid.
- List all the receipt which haven't been paid.

I have created the report without the parameter. How may I adjust these parameters into my report?

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize your query as follows:

```
IF @PAYMENTSTATUS = 'ALL'
BEGIN
SELECT ID, NAME, [DATE], CREATOR, PAYMENTDATE FROM RECEIPT 
WHERE NAME = CASE @NAME WHEN 'ALL' THEN NAME ELSE @NAME END 
END
IF @PAYMENTSTATUS = 'PAID'
BEGIN
SELECT ID, NAME, [DATE], CREATOR, PAYMENTDATE FROM RECEIPT 
WHERE NAME = CASE @NAME WHEN 'ALL' THEN NAME ELSE @NAME END 
AND PAYMENTDATE IS NOT NULL
END
IF @PAYMENTSTATUS = 'UNPAID'
BEGIN
SELECT ID, NAME, [DATE], CREATOR, PAYMENTDATE FROM RECEIPT 
WHERE NAME = CASE @NAME WHEN 'ALL' THEN NAME ELSE @NAME END 
AND PAYMENTDATE IS NULL
END
```

Really it could be simpler if not that I could not figure how to case a date column correctly in SQL where clause, then you would not need 3 if statements.

Next, you can use a different dataset, in parameter properties, get values from a query, to populate your @Name parameter e.g.

```
select 'ALL' 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM RECEIPT
```

Lastly, you can simply use available values for the @PAYMENTSTATUS parameter and specify values 'ALL', 'PAID', 'UNPAID'.